# Highcharts dynamic-update example - adding 1 new value every second - without historic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Using this example code:

http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update

NOTE: There is a link to jsfiddle.net on that page to view the code.

I find that this code example does two basic things:  A) it primes with 1000 random values right as the graph loads, B) it adds a new random item each 1 second.

The problem is when I have no available historic data to populate the initial load, and start with an empty [] series dataset.  The graph doesn't appear or ends up all out of scale. This example's behavior seems dependent on the 1000 values being populated before adding new values.

Does anyone understand my question / problem?

Comment: I can understand there might be some issues, but how do you actually want it to function? What is the specific problem you want solved?

Comment: Well, if you start with no items - [], doing addPoint they do not show up at all. And even if I start with 1 item, the way the chart scrolls is very different from when it starts with 999.  Why should it matter if 999 are added 1 second at a time or 999 added all at once (simulating 1 second apart)?

Comment: I assume what you might be thinking about is that the `addPoint` is shifting out a point when adding a new one, so when you have 1000 points, it stays 1000 points. When you have 1 point, it stays 1 point. 1 point just doesn't make a very good graph. Is that it?

Comment: Thanks @HalvorStrand - that was it - there is a parameter on addPoint function to remove the point, always ending up at zero points if I didn't modify the example further.  If you want, post it as an answer I can accept, or I can even delete the entire question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addPoint` function in your example shifts out the first point when adding a new one, to keep the total number of points at the same value. This is unnoticeable at 1000 points, but if you only have 1 point it will look odd.

The `addPoint` method signature is ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint)):

```
addPoint (Object options, [Boolean redraw], [Boolean shift], [Mixed animation])
```

In the example the code is:

```
series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
```

To remove the shift, remove (or set to `false`) the third parameter:

```
series.addPoint([x, y], true);
```

Or to dynamically keep it at a specific value you could:

```
shift = series.data.length >= 1000 ? true : false;
series.addPoint([x, y], true, shift);
```